# Dynamically changing an image in jquery to match the css image

Tags: jquery, css

Hopefully i'll explain the problem correctly, if not then let me know and I'll make the edit.

I'm created a slide menu that when shown, the background is blurred, this is working ok when it's a static image, the issue i'm having is when it's a slideshow.

This will give you a better understanding of what i'm trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/djm3v/23/

If you click the red button, the background of the slide appears to be blurred, but if you click the next or previous button and show a different slide, the blurred image remains the same, I need it to match the slide image.

Here's my jquery code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".trigger-wrapper").click(function () {
    $("#menu-wrapper-left").stop().animate({width: 'toggle'});
    $('#hero-container').css('background-image','url(http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg)');
    return false;
  });
});
```

The important line is

```
$('#hero-container').css('background-image','url(http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg)');
```

This is the image the slide menu is using to blur, if you delete this line then the slide menu will use the following css image in the stylesheet.

```
#hero-container {
  background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LwilPQw9Zc0/Unzm09oXDxI/AAAAAAAAHwo/30a7ZqSp3jE/s1600/blur-static+.jpg) no-repeat 50% fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Either way both are wrong as it's a single, it needs to use the slideshow images depending on what slide is selected, see below.

```
.hero li:nth-child(1) span { 
  background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg');
}
.hero li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LwilPQw9Zc0/Unzm09oXDxI/AAAAAAAAHwo/30a7ZqSp3jE/s1600/blur-static+.jpg');
}
```

Can anyone help with a working example.

Comment: You'll have to change the background image in the menu whenever you switch image in the slider, but then you'll also have to animate it when you slide to the next image and make it at exactly the same speed. I'm thinking that maybe swapping to a canvas slideshow would be easier. http://tutorialzine.com/2010/09/html5-canvas-slideshow-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question. I have used the same html, javascript and css file from the jsfiddle link and have made some modification in it. I am adding the css where i have done the modification and also the jsfiddle link where i have modified little bit.

CSS

```
#menu-wrapper-left {
    height:100%;
    width:300px;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    background:white;
    top:0;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:5;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    left:0px;
}
```

The completed demo is in the given jsfiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/djm3v/34/

Comment: I've just had a look at the fiddle and the image is no longer blurred?

Comment: Thanks, I can't wait to see it, once done i'll accept and vote up the answer.

Comment: @user1221565 i have added the corrected code and the following is the fiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/djm3v/34/. Does it helped you , the opacity and background :white is the thing that you need

Comment: I would love to accept this answer but I'm not sure you understand the question, when the white slide comes out, the background area should be blurred underneath the white part, if you take a look at the original fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/djm3v/23/ you can see the image is blurred, when you slide to the next image, the image is still blurred but i's the wrong image, I want that image replaced with the one on the slide?

Comment: @user1221565 You have implemented in different way . If i can change the way of the implementation, then i can bring the required output.What do you say.

Comment: With demo of my own images

Comment: Any luck? I'm still tryingly need but getting no further.